# Extrended hex address in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'm having trouble implementing an extended hex value onto my project. When I type `&H000007F0` into my Visual Basic project, Visual Studio goes and shortens it to `&H7F0`.  In a normal situation, that would be fine but I need the preceding 0's to be included as a parameter for a function on an API.

I've tried creating it as a string `Dim MastID As String = "000007F0"` and then converting to a hex `Convert.ToUInt32(MastID, 16)`, but that didn't work like I thought it would. Are there any other methods I can try or a VS17 setting I can turn off/on that will allow me to have the full `&H000007F0`?

I'm doing this to try to connect to a slave device on a CAN bus. I'm using an API that has it's own functions to control the CAN device and initialize a CAN channel. If I am able to pass the extended ID, &H000007F0, then the API would initialize the CAN channel with those parameters.

Parameters being set for slave data:

```
SlaveData.BroadcastID = &H18DAA1E1
SlaveData.MasterID = &H7F0
SlaveData.SlaveID = &H7F2
SlaveData.IncrementalIdUsed = False
```

Function being used:

```
Public Shared Function Connect(
   ByVal Handle As UInt32,
   ByVal Mode As Byte,
   ) As Result ' Returns no errors
End Function
```

Analyzing the CAN BUS, the device ID being used is 7F0h, therefore the slave device does not respond with an acknowledge message. It does however work when I send the same function with the extended master ID my making my own byte array.

Comment: &H00000H7H0 might be a value, but it sure isn't hexidecimal - that only goes up to 'F', not 'H'.

Comment: You don't need the "preceding zeros".  Ask the real question, show your code.

Comment: @Comintern True, I fixed it! My mind is playing tricks on me...

Comment: @HansPassant I'm trying to connect to a slave device on a CAN Bus and I need to use the extended address to connect to it. With out it, the slave device cannot discern that commands sent out arte meant for it.

Comment: If you're communicating with a CAN Bus, why aren't you sending it a byte array? This is pretty much impossible to answer without seeing your code.

Comment: Gosh, I wish! I'm using an API that has its own functions. I'm only able to supply the input variables, such as the Master ID/Slave ID, and it takes care of the channel initialization for me. The IDs have to be UInt32 for the functions to work.

Comment: As others have said, please [edit] your post to include a [mcve].

Comment: *The IDs have to be UInt32*. So, explicitly declare and send `UInt32` values. How is this related whith the value representation *on paper*?

Comment: If you really believe those preceding zeroes matter, go to the Tools Menu->Select Options.  From there, select Text Editor->Basic->Advanced.  Under the _Editor Help_ category, uncheck "Pretty listing (reformatting) code".  You can also ctrl-Z (undo) immediately after VS _corrects_ it.

Comment: Could it be that the endian-ness of the api somewhere is different to your code? I presume that entering 7F00000 doesnt work either?

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out you do not need the leading zeros.  Here is some food for thought...

```
    Dim foo As UInt32 = &H7F0 'note missing 0's

    '  or
    Dim provider As Globalization.CultureInfo = Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
    Dim styles As Globalization.NumberStyles = Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber
    Dim bar As UInt32
    Dim s As String = "000007F0" 'note leading 0's
    If UInt32.TryParse(s, styles, provider, bar) Then
        If foo = bar Then
            Stop ' <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        End If
    End If
```